# How do I prevent rails from rendering public/index.html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm serving and angular 2 app from a rails 5 app. How do I prevent rails from rendering the public/index.html file by default? (This way I can host the apps api through rails and render the angular app too.)

Answer (score 1):

Set `config.public_file_server.index_name = 'other-index'` in your `application.rb` file.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92703a9ea5d8b96f30e0b706b801c9185ef14f0e/railties/test/application/middleware/static_test.rb#L57